# Are exponential functions the only functions that satisfy the equation $f(x+y)g(x+y)= f(x)f(y)g(x)g(y)$ for all nonnegative real numbers $x$ and $y$?

Tags: calculus, functions

We have two functions $f$ and $g$ such that
$f(x+y)g(x+y)= f(x)f(y)g(x)g(y)$ for all nonnegative real numbers $x$ and $y$, what can we say about the two functions?
Exponential forms  satisfy this property but do not know if there exists other forms.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What kind of functions are $f$ and $g$? Are they continuous? Are they real? Do we not assume anything like that? Please give some concrete space of functions you pick these from

Comment: If we had $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ then only exponential functions $x\mapsto \exp(cx)$ would be the solutions, with $c$ depending on $f(1).$ By twisting two possible solutions $f(x),g(x)$ you possibly open a door.

Comment: Also note that if you define $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$, then you must have $h(x+y)=h(x)h(y)$ which is, I think, known... Then you only need to resolve $f(x)g(x)=h(x)$. This approach, however, doesn't hold valid if the structure of codomain is not a field, but an arbitrary ring.

Comment: E.g. we could allow factors: $f(x)=\sqrt{2}\exp(ax)\, , \,g(x)=\sqrt{2}^{-1}\exp(bx)$ which otherwise wouldn't be a solution.